# Are a deity's rank and class levels co-dependent?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, religions-and-deities

I'm trying my hand at making stats for a deity in D&D 3.5 (god of music, if it makes a difference) using the rules given in Deities and Demigods. So far everything makes sense except one thing: I can't tell whether or not his maximum number of class levels is supposed to be connected to his divine rank. Is there any sort of officially-stated correlation between the two, or should I just assume 40 or so levels like most core D&D deities seem to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no connection.

Deities and Demigods has a vague suggestion in the footnote on page 26:

> Most deities are 20 HD outsiders with 30 to 50 character levels as well.

And that's it.

Just add as many class levels as you feel necessary to represent the "mortal" abilities of the deity.

Comment: This pretty much nails it. I found when creating my own deities that it was easiest to build their mortal versions first, then add Divine Ranks as if they were a "god-mode" (heheh) prestige class until I ended up with a deity I was happy with (usually after going back and tweaking things, but this got me to a firm base first). Of course, if you know beforehand how many Divine Ranks you want, it does give you a guide for creating their mortal version to the desired power level.

Comment: @Kromey That's actually pretty good-sounding advice; I know what sort of class levels I planned for him to have, though I suppose building divine ranks from the ground up would help me to just give him the right number of abilities to suit his portfolio better than just picking a rank and filling the slots with somewhat relevant salient abilities.

Question on building the mortal form though, do the Outsider HD grant feats, or do just his class levels?

Comment: @Cobalt If memory serves (and it's been a very long time...) adding monster HD *does* grant feats at the same rate as class levels (i.e. new feat every 4 HD). You also get your ability score point every however-many-HD, same as class levels. That said, I always liked the flavor of "ascended deities" myself, and thus built regular, run-of-the-mill (albeit very epic) characters first, then ascended them with Divine Ranks -- i.e. I didn't bother adding Outsider HD at all.

Comment: @Kromey What about base stats? For mine I just found an average for the total stat points of the D&D Core deities and allocated his stats based off that; what do you usually do about those?

Comment: @Cobalt Depends on how I'm feeling at the moment. Sometimes I'll roll stats just like I would if I were building a PC; other times I'll use an NPC stat array as a starting point; still other times I'll just start with the numbers I want to start with -- heck with the rules, I'm the gorram GM! That's what makes Divine Ranks and Deities and Demigods so awesome, you can build any character you want, however you want, and then ascend her to godhood, to fill any role you'd like. You can also of course just use an existing deity, and either "re-fluff" or tweak as needed.